# highchart polar area chart add legend values inside the chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

this is my polar area chart. - https://ibb.co/H7gJ5DH.

i want to change above polar area chart to look like this - https://ibb.co/ScNwXFB.

```
jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/isurumahesh/2n3jh8xs/48/
```

could you please help me to show the legend values inside the polar area chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one series, disable legend and add another x-axis with the below options:

```
  xAxis: [{
    type: 'category',
    uniqueNames: false,
    gridLineColor: 'black',
    gridZIndex: 5,
    lineWidth: 3,
    labels: {
      staggerLines: 2,
      allowOverlap: true,
      distance: 15,
      align: 'center',
      style: {
        fontSize: '9px',
        width: '70px'
      }
    }
  }, {
    categories: mainCategories,
    min: -0.5,
    max: 3.5,
    offset: -30,
    lineWidth: 0,
    gridLineColor: 'black',
    gridLineWidth: 3,
    gridZIndex: 5,
    showLastLabel: true,
    labels: {
      allowOverlap: true,
      align: 'center',
      staggerLines: 0,
      style: {
        fontSize: '14px'
      }
    }
  }],
  pane: {
    size: '75%'
  },
  yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridZIndex: 5,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    gridLineColor: 'black',
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/za1mq3gc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis

Comment: thank you for your effort. but when i remove one category and the relevant series data, then chart is not rendering properly - https://jsfiddle.net/isurumahesh/k7sefLm0/3/

Comment: Hi @WAEX, That's because you need to adapt the second x-axis extremes, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wjucsady/ You can also do it dynamically, for example in `chart.load` event.